# Error-handling in batch controlled ftp-transfer

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, ftp

I have a script for a customers of us, which transfers one or more files to a remote ftp server.

```
@echo off
@echo %DATE% %TIME% Starte FTP-Transfer. Bitte warten. >>C:\Users\xx\Desktop\log.txt
ftp -s:X:\xxx\FTP-Transfer\Transfer.txt >>C:\Users\xx\Desktop\log.txt
@echo %DATE% %TIME% FTP-Transfer beendet  >>C:\Users\xx\Desktop\log.txt

xcopy X:\xxx\FTP-Transfer\*  X:\xxx\FTP-Transfered\* <<-- copies the transfered files away

echo --- Complete ---
pause   REM delete this in live version!!
```

However i need an error handling of some sort.  What i need is, a way to make sure the transfer has been completed before i copy the files away. The script in Transfer.txt is designed to copy all files in a folder to the remote server and it runs several times a day. Simpliest would be to just let the files in the transfer folder till the transfer has been completed.

Thanks for all suggestions. I'm open to use another ftp program, as long as i can access it in a batch file.

Comment: What shows up in log.txt? I can't access FTP sites from here so I can't test but I'm pretty sure you can just read the output of the log looking for "Transfer complete".

Comment: Here are some other command line FTP clients that are much more powerful than MS FTP. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), [Wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: Thanks, looks like the WinSCP will do it. Didn't know that it supports cli.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be as simple as checking to see if the file exists in a different directory, correct?

```
if exist File.txt (
    ECHO File exists
)
```

Then in the code block, set a variable that will describe if the file exists or not, then insert another If block for copying the files away